# Change in Syntax causes different results in output

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The code:-

```
    def build_graph_year(self,year):
    data=self.req_da(0,year)
    n=[]
    h=[]
    for i in data:
        t=''
        for x in range(0,len(i),1):
            z=i[x]
            if z!='-':
                t=t+z
            if z=='-':
                n.append(t)
                h.append(i[x+1:])
    fig=plt.figure("Graph For Year {0}".format(year))
    rect=fig.patch
    rect.set_facecolor('green')
    pos=np.arange(0,len(n),1)+1
    graph1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    graph1.barh(pos,h,align='center',color='r')
    graph1.set_xlabel('Height',color='w')
    graph1.set_ylabel('Names',color='w')
    graph1.set_title('Height Of Students in the year {0}'.format(year),color='w')
    graph1.tick_params(axis='x',color='w')
    graph1.tick_params(axis='y',color='w')
    graph1.spines['top'].set_color('black')
    graph1.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
    graph1.spines['left'].set_color('black')
    graph1.spines['right'].set_color('black')
    plt.yticks(pos,n)#OVER HERE
    plt.show()
```

The code works fine. But when I swap the "plt" in the second last line with "graph1" , the tick postions are no longer replaced by the Strings stored in the list n. An error occurs instead:-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "F:\Python\Python-Programs\Graph_use_1_heights.py", line 109, in <module>
   h.build_graph_year('2016')
 File "F:\Python\Python-Programs\Graph_use_1_heights.py", line 105, in build_graph_year
   graph1.yticks(pos,n)
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'yticks'
```

But if I replace '.yticks' with '.set_yticks', No more error occurs but the tick positions are not replaced by the strings in the list n.[image]

Why does this happen and what is the difference between graph.set_yticks(pos,n)
and plt.yticks(pos,n)?

Comment: I believe the difference is choosing to **plot** the y_ticks and choosing to set the value of the **y_ticks** contained in the graph1 object.

Comment: I am setting the value of yticks in the graph1 object before plotting, so shouldn't it plot them out as modified by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've confused about

1. [`matplotlib.pyplot.yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks): it can either "Get or set the y-limits of the current tick locations and labels". When setting labels, it accepts locs and labels, "where locs is an array of tick locations and labels is an array of tick labels". In your case `plt.yticks(pos,n)`, both `pos` and `n` are appropriate arguments.
2. [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html): it "Set the y ticks with list of ticks". It requires one `ticks` argument which "ACCEPTS: sequence of floats" (for tick locations). It can also take a keyword argument `minor` which is a boolean variable. In your case `graph1.set_yticks(pos, n)`, `pos` is an appropriate argument but `n` is converted and taken as a boolean `True`. In other words, your `graph1.set_yticks(pos, n)` is equal to `graph1.set_yticks(pos, True)`.
3. [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html): it "Set the y tick labels with list of strings labels". It requires one `labels` argument which can be your `n`. It can also take a few keyword arguments.

As explain above, your `plt.yticks(pos,n)` sets both tick locations and labels, while your `graph1.set_yticks(pos, n)` sets only tick locations. That's why you didn't see y labels. If you want to set y labels, the following two lines are equal to `plt.yticks(pos,n)`:

```
graph1.set_yticks(pos)
graph1.set_yticklabels(n)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Luo. The problem was solved and I understood the cause.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry to be redundant. I didn't realize you've already got the answer.

Comment: I meant the problem was solved from your answer and I understood what the cause was.